# bot sends the message to the group several times

Tags: python, telegram-bot

```py
def telegram_bot_sendtext():
    
    bot_token = 'bot token'
    bot_chatID = 'chat id'
    text = ['done!','save']
    for i in text:
        send_text = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + bot_token + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + bot_chatID + '&parse_mode=Markdown&text=' + i  
        requests.get(send_text)
        time.sleep(4)


@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=[chat id]))
async def handler(event):
    print(event)
    event_message = event.message
    telegram_bot_sendtext()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

I wrote this code but the bot sends the message to the group several times, what should I do?

Comment: You're sending both the 'done!' and 'save' message separate. Thats normal since you're looping through the list

Comment: Going off @0stone0's comment - what did you *expect* to happen when you ran this code?

Comment: For every message that is sent in the group, the bot sends only one message

Answer (score 0):

Even if I do not list and send a single message, it sends the message continuously